# Linq query where Contains() checks for list of strings

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the Following Query:

```
var query = from o in this.OrderManager.LoadOrders()
            join s in this.SkuManager.LoadSkus() on o.SKU equals s.SKU
            where o.ORDER_ID == orderId
            let parcelItem = o.RPU != "Y" && o.DROP_SHIP != "Y" && s.TRUCK_SHIP != "T" && o.SKU != "ABC-123" && o.SKU != "XYZ-789" && o.SKU != "JKL-456"
            select new OrderMailLineItem
            {
                OrderId = o.ORDER_ID,
                Sku = s.SKU,
                WarehouseId = s.SITE_ID,
                QualifyingItem = qualifyingItem,
                OversizedItem = parcelItem && (s.DROP_SHIP == null)
            };
```

I would like to be able to write the line `let parcelItem = ...` to be more like `!o.SKU.Contains(skuList)` where:

```
List<string> skuList = new List<string> { "ABC-123", "XYZ-789", "JKL-456"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether SKU is not in list instead of checking whether list is in SKU:

```
let parcelItem = !skuList.Contains(o.SKU)
```

Answer (score 0):

`!skuList.Contains(o.SKU)` is exactly how you'd usually do it.

But you could write an `In` operator, if you like:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T t, params T[] values)
        => values.Contains(t);
}
```

...

```
        let parcelItem = o.RPU != "Y" && o.DROP_SHIP != "Y" && s.TRUCK_SHIP != "T" && 
                        !o.SKU.In("ABC-123", "XYZ-789", "JKL-456")
```

I doubt that'll work with Linq to SQL though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this wouldn't work. You would just need to check those three Yes/No flags in addition to your SKU list.

```
var skuList = new[] { "ABC-123", "XYZ-789", "JKL-456"};
var query = from o in this.OrderManager.LoadOrders()
        join s in this.SkuManager.LoadSkus() on o.SKU equals s.SKU
        where o.ORDER_ID == orderId
        let parcelItem = o.RPU != "Y" && o.DROP_SHIP != "Y" && s.TRUCK_SHIP != "T" && skuList.Contains(o.SKU)
        select new OrderMailLineItem
        {
            OrderId = o.ORDER_ID,
            Sku = s.SKU,
            WarehouseId = s.SITE_ID,
            QualifyingItem = qualifyingItem,
            OversizedItem = parcelItem && (s.DROP_SHIP == null)
        };
```